# Short exact sequence for the structure sheaf of the union of two irreducible subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Z_1$, $Z_2$ be two irreducible subvarieties of $X$.

Does the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{Z_1 \cup Z_2}$ fit in a short exact sequence involving structure and ideal sheaves of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ in the general case of non-empty and non-transverse intersection?

Comment: For every two ideals $I_1,I_2$ in a ring $A$ there is the exact sequence $0\to A/(I_1\cap I_2) \to A/I_1 \oplus A/I_2 \to A/(I_1+I_2) \to 0$. Taking sheaves we get the exact sequence $ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_{Z_1\cup Z_2} \to \mathcal{O}_{Z_1}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{Z_2} \to \mathcal{O}_{Z_1\cap Z_2} \to 0$.